# Redirect WordPress Blog to HTTPS installed in sub-directory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl, mod-rewrite, https

I have a non wordpress website on www.payexchanger.com and installed SSL on this and its working good.

Well now I installed wordpress in a sub-directory (not sub-domain) which www.payexchanger.com/pe (so its public_html/pe)

Now I have two problems, one is that SSL is broken on wordpress and second all pages are not being redirected to https.

I added this in .htaccess file here `public_html/pe`

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.payexchanger.com/pe/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```